# adb shell mount error: mount: '/dev/block/dm-0' not user mountable in fstab

Tags: android, adb, mount, fstab

I needs to write a shell app to a system partition of my emulator to get elevated permission, so I first run the mount command:

```
adb shell 'mount -o rw,remount /'
```

and I'm getting error:

```
mount: '/dev/block/dm-0' not user mountable in fstab
```

The system image of my emulator is **Automotive with Play Store ARM 64 v8a System Image**, I'm running it in Android studio on my Mac with apple chip(which can only run arm images).

Comment: One possible reason is the system image is a production build so I cannot run adb as root user, if that's the cause then I have to find a dev/test image.

Comment: AFAIK all emulator images provided by Google don't have root support. Remounting system partition requires root permissions, therefore this will not work, unless you root the emulator image or build your own emulator image with included app.

Comment: Got it, that makes sense, thanks Robert.